# FacebookSDK-4.4.1 share local picture without the app install and public_actions permission

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to share a local picture to the facebook,my facebook sdk is 4.4.1.below is my code:

```
 private void shareContentToFacebook(){
    SharePhoto sharePhoto = new SharePhoto.Builder()
            .setBitmap(mBitmap)
            .build();
    ArrayList<SharePhoto> photos = new ArrayList<>();
    photos.add(sharePhoto);

    SharePhotoContent sharePhotoContent =
            new SharePhotoContent.Builder().setPhotos(photos)
            .build();

    if (mShareDialog.canShow(SharePhotoContent.class)) {
        mShareDialog.show(sharePhotoContent);
    } else if (hasPublishPermission()){
        ShareApi.share(sharePhotoContent, null);
    } else {
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(PhotoPreviewFragment.this,
            Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
    }

}
```

if i have install the facebook app,it works well with

```
mShareDialog.show(sharePhotoContent);
```

if not,it will come to login code:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(PhotoPreviewFragment.this,
            Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
```

when login success,i will transfer the method shareContentToFacebook again：

```
 LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            shareContentToFacebook();
            Log.d("XXX", "LoginSuccess!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(null);
            Log.d("XXX", "onCancel!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(null);
            Log.d("XXX","facebook error:"+e.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

but i cannot get the permission public_actions,so i cannot go inside

```
ShareApi.share(sharePhotoContent, null);
```

do you have any solutions to share a photo without facebook app install and public_actions?